# (How) can I suppress the warning that a package configuration file was not found?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

I'm trying to create a `CMakeLists.txt` file which tries finding `Qt5`, and if that fails, tries falling back to a `Qt4` installation. The script works so far, but I'll always get a warning if `Qt5` is not installed.

Note that `FindQt5.cmake` is supplied by `Qt5` and will not be available if only `Qt4` is installed.

The basic structure is like this:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

message("-- Searching for Qt5")
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Xml Network)

if (Qt5_FOUND)
  message("-- Searching for Qt5 - found version ${Qt5Core_VERSION}")        
else (Qt5_FOUND)
  message("-- Searching for Qt5 - not found") 
  # ...
endif (Qt5_FOUND)
```

The warning message in case `Qt5` is not installed (or not set up properly) is the following:

> By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
>   has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
>   "Qt5", but CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with
>   any of the following names:
>
> Qt5Config.cmake
>       qt5-config.cmake
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>   "Qt5_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.If
>   "Qt5" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
>   been installed.

Is there a way to suppress this warning? 
I'll also accept other ways to detect if `Qt5` is installed or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to suppress the warning, the `QUIET` keyword can be used:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Xml Network QUIET)
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_package` has `CONFIG` and `MODULE` arguments to tell cmake how to search for the package.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html

Add the `CONFIG` keyword.