# how to silence warning of cmake's find_package when it fail to find?

Tags: c++, cmake

here is part of my CMakeLists.txt

```
  find_package(Catch2)
if(TARGET Catch2::Catch2)
  message("catch2 has been installed previously")
  include(Catch)
else()
  message("no target catch2")

  include(FetchContent)
  # Download and configure Catch2 for the tests
  FetchContent_Declare(
    catch2
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2
    GIT_TAG master
    )

  FetchContent_GetProperties(catch2)
  if (NOT catch2_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(catch2)
    add_subdirectory(${catch2_SOURCE_DIR} ${catch2_BINARY_DIR})
    list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${catch2_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib)
    include(Catch)
  endif()

endif()
```

What I want to do is if catch2 is available, then use directly, else, download from github automatically. It works fine now, other than this annoying warning:

```
CMake Warning at test/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindCatch2.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Catch2", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Catch2" with any
  of the following names:

    Catch2Config.cmake
    catch2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Catch2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Catch2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Catch2"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

So, how to silence this warning?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144327/how-can-i-suppress-the-warning-that-a-package-configuration-file-was-not-found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `QUIET`, as follows:

```
find_package(PackageName QUIET)
```

> If the package configuration file cannot be found CMake will generate an error describing the problem unless the QUIET argument is specified.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/find_package.html?highlight=i